# Click cell to redirect to other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that hides all of the sheets on my spreadsheet except for one. Additionally, on the main sheet when I double click a cell on column E it redirect me to one of the hidden sheets. The problem is that it is re-directing me to the wrong sheet and I don't know why. See code below.

When I click cell "E3" I want to go to "Sheet 1" instead I am being re-directed to "Sheet 2". This is happening to all of them where I am redirected to the sheet mentioned directly below instead of the desired one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Main" Then
        ws.Visible = True
        Else
        ws.Visible = False
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target.Address
Case "$E$3"
Sheets("Sheet 1").Visible = True
Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate
Case "$E$4"
Sheets("Sheet 2").Visible = True
Sheets("Sheet 2").Activate
Case "$E$5"
Sheets("Sheet 3").Visible = True
Sheets("Sheet 3").Activate
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you do E3?

Comment: Your double click event activates the sheet which runs the Activate code which hides the sheet and hence the next one appears.

Comment: I am not having any problems with when I only have the two codes in the worksheet code for the `Main` sheet.

Comment: What do you double-click on each sheet to get back to the Main worksheet?

Answer (score 3):

I would humbly suggest you get rid of the repetitious code in each worksheet's code sheet and aggregate all of the actionable code into the ThisWorkbook code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If LCase(Sh.Name) = "main" Then
        Cancel = True
        Select Case Target.Address
            Case "$E$3"
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True   '<~~ see footnote ¹
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            Case "$E$4"
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            Case "$E$5"
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Cancel = True
        Worksheets("Main").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Main").Activate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Sh.Visible = False
End Sub
```

This returns to the Main worksheet whenever A1 on any other worksheet is double-clicked.

¹ <sub>I have changed the names of your worksheets from `Sheet 1` to `Sheet1`.</sub>